# Projecting onto the span of a generic Veronese variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\sigma_d:\mathbb{P}^2\to\mathbb{P}^n$ be the d-th Veronese map and let $X=\sigma_d(\mathbb{P}^2)$. Let $W\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a 2-plane such that $W\cap X=\emptyset$. For a line $L\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ let $X_L=\sigma_d(L)$.
Since $\dim(L)=1$ the space $U_L$ spanned by $X_L$ has dimension $d$ which is basically the Veronese of $\mathbb{P}^1$ in different coordinates.

If $d\ge 4$, is it true that for generic $L$ the projection of $W$ onto $U_L$ does not intersect $X_L$ and still has dimension 2?

Dimensionwise this should be true since in $U_L$, $X_L$ has dimension 1 and $W$ has dimension at most 3.

Comment: The projection from where? I think it makes a difference. Perhaps you mean generic projection? But then isn’t the image simply a general plane in $U_L$?

Comment: First you say $W$ is a $2$-plane. Then, you ask if the projection of $W$ onto $U_L$ "still has dimension $3$". Can you please explain? Is $W$ supposed to have dimension $2$, or $3$? (Typo maybe?)

Comment: yeah sry that was a typo. it should be a 2 plane in both cases. To clarify the projection: I want to take the orthogonal projection onto $U_L$.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "orthogonal projection" in the context of projective space?

Comment: E.g., if $U$ is the span of $(1,\sqrt{-1},0)$ (a line) then what would you say is the orthogonal complement of $U$? Is it all right if $U$ is included in its orthogonal complement? - Is it all right if $U$ is included in the kernel of the orthogonal projection onto $U$? - I think that your original question is interesting but the issue of "which projection" is important and I don't think it can be answered by saying, orthogonal projection.

Comment: yeah you are right, this does not really make sense. So assume that $W$ is the vector space spanned $f_1,f_2,f_3\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]_d$ and $\mathbb{P}W$ the corresponding projective 2-plane. Now let $L$ be a generic linear form, $L=ax+by-z$. Then I wanted to consider the space spanned by $f_i(x,y,ax+by)$ inside $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_d$ and ask if there is a $d-$th power of some linear form in this space. But I think you are right and this is not what I wrote in the question. I hope this is formulated correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true as stated in the comments. Consider $W=x_3^{d-2}\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]_2$ and $l$ a generic linear form. Then $W(x_1,x_2,l)=l^{d-2}\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]_2$ and then setting $x_3=0$ gives $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]\supseteq W'=l'^{d-2}\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2]_2$. But $W'$ contains $l'^d$. If $l$ does not contain $x_3$ then the dimension of $W'$ is not three anymore.